# How to fix CSS in wordpress after transfer it from localhost?

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, localhost

I am working for a client on creating a WordPress site for her. I have worked from a "[www.test-accounts.co.uk](http://test-accounts.co.uk)" and all works fine. Now I have finished and I am transferring it to the live site that the client already has "[www.lebaneat.co.uk](http://lebaneat.co.uk)"

However, CSS is not working. I try to replace the URL in the DB manually, I tried to use a tool in the dashboard, I tried to many things but still nothing.

Can someone look at both sites I put up and give me an indication of where to look to?

Comment: Do you copy all files from "test-accounts.co.uk" to the new side or are you adjusting the paths?

Comment: I downloaded all the files and db then I uploaded it to the new site and make changes of the URL on the db and etc.

Comment: I think you're having some issues with your DB. Is your DB contains Capital letters when naming it? I mean the DB name.

Comment: Are you reinstalling Wordpress right now? Because when I call the webpage it asks me to install it

Comment: sorry, I was re-upload the db again

Comment: No, it does not contain any capital letters at all

Comment: Now it works, how did you solve it?

Comment: i did not solve it at all. that one is de old files I had for the client - I still struggle find solution. I had to put the old content back on because the client asked to do so until i find the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [DB Search Replace](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/). WP keep some data as serialized strings and some are backslash escaped. DB Search Replace will replace occurrences in both.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. I have already used it too but still not working either

Comment: http and https? Check your protocols. Production site under https display Revolution Slider + jQuery related error.

Comment: how can I check the protocols. what you mean? Should I change it to http instead of https?

Comment: It's up to you. But it's clear that the site need some debugging. Enable error reporting or monitor you error log. There are php code at the front page:

...
jQuerytheCatId = get_term_by( 'slug', 'tutorials', 'category' );

Answer (score 1):

SQL Queries to Change Website Domain

https://rudrastyh.com/tools/sql-queries-generator

When moving WordPress websites from one domain to another, this tool is a great time saver. Just generate the queries and run them in MySQL.

Comment: On that webpage, there are 3 style.css files so your CSS might be overridden by other CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the site URL from the database with the new URL. Go to wp_options table and change the site URL from there

Comment: I have already done that. That was the first thing i did but still not working

Comment: If you have used any caching plugin then remove the cache folder or disable the plugin and then try again!

Answer (score 0):

Did you have change all the url of youre website ?
you can do it with :

```html
# Change URL

UPDATE wp_options
SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://localhost/wordpress', 'http://newwebsite.com')
WHERE option_name = 'home'
OR option_name = 'siteurl';

# Change URL  GUID

UPDATE wp_posts
SET guid = REPLACE (guid, 'http://localhost/wordpress', 'http://newwebsite.com');

# Change URL  médias articles pages

UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content, 'http://localhost/wordpress', 'http://newwebsite.com');

# Change URL meta

UPDATE wp_postmeta
SET meta_value = REPLACE (meta_value, 'http://localhost/wordpress','http://newwebsite.com');
```

Comment: ok, when i go to http://lebaneat.co.uk i have the wordpress installation page, this is normal ?

Comment: sorry, I was re-upload the db. check it again

Answer (score 0):

There is a great plugin to change all URL in your WP, it's [Velvet Blues Update URLs](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/)

I use it for all my transfert in production.

I hope this will help you. ;)